# Why does my iPad app display as iPhone app mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Actually I'm making an `Universal` app that will run both in iPhone and iPad.But I find it can not be recognized right in iPad, some time it displays as iPad mode, some time it displays as iPhone mode.In the simulator, usually it presents iPhone mode at the first time launch, then don't stop it, just run the app from xcode again, it presents iPad mode rightly .I couldn't find the reason.So I change the `Device` option in `Summary` from `Universal` to `iPad` only, but everything goes the same.I checked the `Targeted Device Family` option in `Build Settings`, the value of it is `iPad`. Everything looks right, but why comes that?

Addition: I write the UI by code with no Storyboard and nib, and use `NSLayoutConstraint` to make it layout automatically.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You mean that only sometimes it shows as iPad in the simulator ?

[image: Click the bar and choose device] 
If you just click the bar (next to the run/stop buttons), and choose device :)

Comment: Sorry, what is wrong with this answer ? If I didn't understood your question correctly, could you please be more specific ?